# Problem from CodeWars It returns 5 instead of 23 . Can someone help me understand my code?

Tags: python

**Problem**:

If we list all the *natural numbers below 10* that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The *sum* of these multiples is 23.

Finish the solution so that it `return`s the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below the number passed in.

**Note**: If the number is a multiple of both 3 and 5, only count it once.

**Code**:

```
def solution(number): 
    return sum( (i%3==0 or i%5==0) for i in range (number))

solution(10)
```

Comment: Try `print([(i%3==0 or i%5==0) for i in range (number)])`…

Comment: Your problem is that you don't reduce the task, a.k.a. extracting a [mcve]. Doing so, you would have found the mistake yourself. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

The problem asks you to sum the numbers which are multiples of 3 or 5, but here you're summing the result of `(i%3==0 or i%5==0)`, which is a boolean (which in Python is equal to the integers 0 and 1).

Meaning you're just *counting* the number of multiples of 3 and 5, not summing them. This can trivially be checked by just running the function locally in a Python shell: you'll get 5 (because `range` starts at 0 inclusive, so while 0 does not matter to the sum it matters to the counting).

A generator comprension is "value returned [for] value [in] producer [if] condition". Your test needs to go at the end, as a condition.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are summing the boolean values that's why your answer is not correct please try following code

**Code:**

```
def solution(number): 
    return sum( i for i in range (number) if (i%3==0 or i%5==0))

solution(10)
```

Answer (score -1):

In each iteration of the loop, you are evaluating the condition

`(i%3==0 or i%5==0)`

which is True exactly five times when `number` is 10.  Each `True` counts as a `1`, hence you get 5 for the sum.

To get the correct answer, you need to rearrange the statement so that you evaluate `i` whenever your condition is true. For more details, see [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).